# IntelliJ IDEA w/ Scala Plugin not finding scala.concurrent

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I am having the hardest time getting a fresh install of IntelliJ to work properly with Scala.

I've installed IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.4 and the Scala plugin on a Mac. In any project, the IDE complains it cannot find scala.concurrent (or any other package in scala-library) even though the library is listed under "External Libraries". What am I missing?

I've got the basic steps to reproduce down to:

1. Install IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.4
2. Install Scala plugin via IntelliJ plugins dialog
3. Create a new Scala project (either SBT or non-SBT, doesn't matter)
4. Define a new class and try to import scala.concurrent._

[image: IntelliJ IDEA cannot resolve symbol concurrent]

This happens with new or existing projects - even when provisioned via `sbt gen-idea`.

I've installed Scala and SBT via brew and even tried setting $SCALA_HOME to point to the brew install of scala (`/usr/local/share/scala`).

IntelliJ is listing the library in External Libraries but still can't resolve the symbol.

[image: IntelliJ IDEA lists scala-library in External Libraries]

I have been fighting with this for hours. What am I missing here?

Comment: You can go in file -> project structure -> modules and check if the scala module and check that the project structure is correctly built  and/or the scala module is there.

Comment: I get this kind of errors when the JDK setting for a project is wrong, check that!

Comment: I have the same issue, did you figure out a solution for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same issue. I fixed it with Invalidate Caches

**File | Invalidate Caches / restart**. Manual way on Mac with removing this folder:

~/Library/Caches/IntelliJIDEAXX

Comment: It annoys me to no end that this actually fixed my problem.  Anyone have a pointer to docs on precisely _what_ IDEA caches and _when_?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and above advice didn't help me. After googling and reading JetBrains tickets, I found out that I had $JAVA_HOME variable pointing to JDK 1.7:
    JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home

Removing that from both current shell (`unset JAVA_HOME`) and shell's profile (in my case `.zshrc`) resolved the issue.