# Intellij has wrong scala syntax errors

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I have this piece of code:

```
object Application {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

    val ws = new NingWSClient(new AsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder().build())
    ws.url("https://www.google.com").get() onSuccess {
      case resp: WSResponse => {
        println("Hello");
      }
      case _ => {
        println("Error");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Every dependency is well defined inside the `build.sbt` like so:

```
name := "example"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.4"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-ws" % "2.4.0-M2",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.4.0-M2"
)
```

But Intellij looks like this when viewing my project:

[image: Intellij]

Could somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong because I'm clueless and this is really annoying because my imports are constantly being removed by Intellij.

Comment: Don't you need a `match` statement to use pattern matching?

Comment: @BoristheSpider Still, should not make a difference, should it?

Comment: The onSuccess method takes a PartialFunction and Scala generates one from a brace enclosed group of case statements, so there's nothing wrong there. I do see several other things wrong here. The red highlighting of concurrent and println indicate that for some reason IntelliJ is not finding the Scala library. This could be the entirety of the problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [IntelliJ IDEA w/ Scala Plugin not finding scala.concurrent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26090385/intellij-idea-w-scala-plugin-not-finding-scala-concurrent)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This looks like an IntelliJ (or Scala plugin) bug. Sometimes scala namespace does not seem to be handled well - I have seen it with my projects as well since I gave upgraded to version 14. Sometimes it helps to use [File / Invalidate Caches/Restart](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/cleaning-system-cache.html).

Sometimes even adding / removing Scala SDK and invalidating caches does not help. In such case installing scalap.jar from [issue SCL-8025 Standard scala library unrecognized on sbt project creation on 2.11.4](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-8025) might help (the scala plugin location was `%userprofile%\.IntelliJIdea14\config\plugins\Scala\lib` on my computer).

Another [issue SCL-7900
Scala import/auto-complete problem](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-7900) seems to suggest the problem shows when Idea uses JRE from Java 8 - uninstalling 1.8 JDK or setting a IDEA_JDK_64 variable to point to jdk7-64bit files is also supposed to fix the issue.

Comment: Your suggestion worked perfectly! I also added a local Scala SDK to the module which, combined with the Invalidate Caches, did the trick!